# simpleSaml Passive authentication not working or wong configuration?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

I have 2 SPs that use the same idP.

The idP uses simplesamlphp, and I have the 2 SPs configured in `saml20-sp-remote.php`

The 2 SPs use laravel, and I am able to login using each of the SPs individually, and am able to use the same login in the 2 SPs, as expected.

I do believe that I am missing something here to achieve passive authentication.

What I am trying to do is: I click on the login link on SP1, I get redirected to the login page on my idP and after that to the callback URL in SP1. I can confirm that I am authenticated in SP1, and I would like to go to SP2, click the login link and get redirected back with a login, which doesn't happen. If I set passive mode to true I simply get redirected back with no user logged in, and if I set passive mode to false I get the login form, so I need to insert the same credentials for logging into SP2.

What am I missing?

Just to allow a more detailed troubleshooting or others finding this in the future, I am using the `Aacotroneo\Saml2` package for Laravel.

I have overridden the default login method in the SAMLController to this (this was actually the second version, the first parameter was set to get back to the default login URL and I forwarded it to the ACS route hoping to reuse the existing logic):

```
public function login(Saml2Auth $saml2Auth)
    $saml2Auth->login('/sso/acs', [], false, true, false, true);    
}
```

Regardless of the redirection URL, I am not able to login with isPassive set to true (4th parameter).

I have looked into the idP logs and also tracked down the error in the callback in Laravel to this message:

> The status code of the Response was not Success, was Responder >
> Passive authentication not supported.

However, I have read that this error can be triggered either by a nonexisting login in idP for that SP as well as for other reasons.

With that in mind, I am a little bit lost.

It seems like the idP is not recognizing the SPs as being related, and does not tell SP2 that there is a user logged in from SP1.

Any hints on missing configurations or additional troubleshooting I can do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you also get the login screen again on your IdP even when passive turned *off*, the problem is not in the use of isPassive, but appearently your IdP does not support single sign on or it does not work. Maybe there's a session management issue (something with cookies, session storage backend or periodic cleanup) that prevents the SimpleSAML IdP from finding the session of returning ussers?

Comment: The weirdest thing is that I have made some changes to the php code of the idp login form to print the contents of the session variable, and it shows details about the user I logged in with previously, and still shows the form as if I wasn't logged in